# How to show xxhdpi images on a xhdpi device?

Tags: android, image-resizing

I have a Kindle Fire HDX 7", which has a **1200 x 1920 px** resolution, and **xhdpi** density.

When I run my workout app on it, the exercise illustrations are very small - I think the device takes the xhdpi images, because that's the devices default density. However, some other apps (3 out of 10 tested) are showing bigger images, as if Kindle knows, that it needs to show the xxhdpi versions.

Here's an example of my app (left image) and a similar app (right image) from another developer, who got it right.

[Side-by-side screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxfpB.jpg)

It seems that those 3 developers figured it out, how to show xxhdpi images on xhdpi devices.

I'd appreciate your help on this. The app looks way better, if a correct image size is shown.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more information ... e.g. https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/targeting-amazon-devices-with-your-android-manifest and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html#Enable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines about asking Questions on the site in the [Help]. You're expected to show the code relevant to the question...

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @IanB: my programmer already solved the issue, but thanks for your willingness to help. He created a new folder for tablets and has put the images there; Cindy Meister: sorry about that, I will read the Guidelines now. Please feel free to delete this thread since I won't be able to participate in a technical manner. :-( Thanks.